# Asymptotes of a conicoid

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

What do we mean by asymptotes of a conicoid ?

The asymptotes of below conicoid
$$ax^2+by^2+cz^2=1$$
is the cone
$$ax^2+by^2+cz^2=0$$

We can derive this by the general definition of a asymptotes . Mathematics seems correct here.
However , i cannot visualize how a cone can meet a fixed surface(in this case a conicoid) at infinity ?
What do we mean by asymptote of a cone ,cylinder etc. ?

Comment: The second one is only a cone if the sign of one of $a, b, c$ differs from the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will help:

[image]

The outer surface is the hyperboloid $x^{2} + y^{2} - z^{2} = 1$, and the inner surface is the cone $x^{2} + y^{2} - z^{2} = 0$. You can see that the surfaces get closer together as $z$ goes to $\pm\infty$.

Comment: Thanks , the answer was helpful .However , i have a question here. In textbooks , i have seen that in deriving the equation of asypmtotes of a curve , we start by taking an arbitrary line and making sure that the line meets the curve at infinity . Then , we find the locus of all such lines which gives us our required asymptotic curve. Is this approach correct ?

Comment: Do you have any other approach ?

Comment: Is there a standard way to find asymptotes of a curve ?

Comment: Take the limit as whichever variable goes to infinity and simplify things. For example, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{3}}{x^{2} + 1} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{1 + \frac{1}{x}} = x$ because the $\frac{1}{x}$ goes to $0$. Thus, an asymptote of that curve is $y = x$.

Comment: In this case, $z(x, y) = \pm\sqrt{x^{2} +y^{2} - 1}$, and

$$\lim_{z\to\pm\infty}z(x,y) = \lim_{z\to\pm\infty}\pm\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2} - 1} = \pm\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}$$

Note that the result is the relation for the cone.

Comment: I don't fully understand how the last limit came ?. As $z\to\infty$ ,  $x\to\infty$  and $y\to\infty$ . How did $-1$ disappear ? Sorry for bothering late.